# Where can I get intro to basic personal finance terms? I'm a software engineer

Tags: finance

I am a software engineer. I might be working on a project in near future that will require some knowledge of basic finance terms.

I never had any course about finance or accounting in college or university. There will be a financial expert on project to guide the engineers but I also want to gain some knowledge about subject.

I would like to know if there is any book or small tutorial available that can teach me the basics. I searched online but could not find.

Some of the terms are Debt, Mortgage, Liquid Debt, Net Worth, Investment and Growth Rate, Loan, Credit Card and Interest rate, Ownership etc.

I can search for these terms online and understand but I don't want to be limited to these, I want to know the basics and there must be more terms there if our project grows in future.

- It is quite possible that all of these terms are easily understood to you, so please don't say this is 8th grade knowledge :)

Comment: This is too basic for this site. You could ask your expert advice on some textbook relevant to your area and maybe ask a general "How do I gain expertise question on X which is related to my job" at workplace.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hillier, Ross, Westerfield, Jaffe, Jordan: Corporate Finance

Read this book. I was recommended to use this book for the citation of basic terms in my thesis. I was surprised how well and easy it was explained. It has also a good structure. If you go to a university library, you will most likely find it, which you can borrow then.

Edit: If you want to look up just a few terms: go to investopedia. They're not always that scientific, but for the basic purposes of understanding the terms it's mostly sufficient.